# How to configure Apache Airflow with Celery, SQS and Postgres

Tags: celery, airflow, amazon-sqs, celery-task, messagebroker

I am having problem with setting airflow configuration using SQS and Postgres.

I did following configuration in airflow.cfg

Celery configuration:

```
result_backend =  db+postgresql://xxx:yyy@zzz:5432/airflow  
broker_url = sqs:// #Configure IAM role for the SQS on EC2
```

Airflow Configuration:

```
executor = CeleryExecutor  
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://xxx:yyy@yyy:5432/airflow_db
```

When I start airflow webserver, it is working fine without any issue, but when I starts airflow celery worker I getting following error

```
\[2022-03-25 02:03:49 -0500\] \[16054\] \[ERROR\] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 8793)  

\[2022-03-25 02:04:31,329: WARNING/MainProcess\] No hostname was supplied.  
 Reverting to default 'None'
\[2022-03-25 02:04:31,329: ERROR/MainProcess\] consumer: Cannot connect to **sqs://localhost//**: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://queue.amazonaws.com/".  
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

Please help if anyone knows the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/22863

This issue and discussion may help these problems?
Note: SQS for Celery broker is not officially supported by airflow for now.
See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/24019

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).